# Comment block icon is not visible in excel vba

Tags: vba, vbe

I tried searching in various forum but could't find the answer. I am unable to find the comment block option in excel vba.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooxob.png)

Comment: There's no block comment in VBA, only line comments. Right-click the toolbar, select "customize", customize as needed.

Answer (score 1):

View - Toolbars and select the Edit toolbar, and it's on there.

Comment: I did tried those steps but was unsuccessful, Earlier it was visible, now it is not(refer the image attached)

Comment: Must have been removed. Select the Edit toolbar in the Customize dialog, then click the `Reset...` button.